# Finding whether checkbox is checked or not using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery. I have below the code to find out whether the check box is checked or not. But though the check box is checked it always goes to else block in below the code:

```
if ($('#someId').is(':checked')) {
    alert("checked");
} else {
    alert("unchecked");
}
```

Html code:

By default the check box is not checked. The code is as below.

```
<td>    
    select :<br><input type="checkbox" id="someId" name="someId" value="">                      
</td>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong?: http://jsfiddle.net/fEThD/

Comment: have you put your javascript code into DOM-ready event, i.e. `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: What event causes the code to run?

Comment: On check box selection i am not doing anything. have one submit button. On submit, am checking whether the checkbox is checked or not...on check box selection should i set the value to checked?

Comment: Is this functionality wrapped in $().ready()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 select :<input type="checkbox" id="someId" name="someId" value="" checked />
 <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit"/>

 $("#btnSubmit").on("click",function(){
     if ($("#someId").is(':checked')) {
        alert("checked");
     } else {
        alert("unchecked");
     } 
  });
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tLebs/1/

i hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. On check box selection i am not doing anything. have one submit button. On submit, am checking whether the checkbox is checked or not...on check box selection should i set the value to checked?

Answer (score 1):

Skip jQuery's methods for this if you're only dealing with one checkbox: the DOM `checked` property is as easy as it could possibly be. jQuery only confuses the issue. Feel free to use jQuery to get hold of the element though.

```
var isChecked = $("#someId")[0].checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am throwing out a guess that you need a  doc ready function

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#someId").on("click",function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           alert("checked");
         } else {
           alert("unchecked");
         } 
      });
 });`
```

see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($("#Your_CheckBox").is(':checked')) {

    }
```